# How to remove showing the warning from every line in eclipse 2023-03?

Tags: eclipse

Suddenly my eclipse 2023-03 started showing the following.

[image]

**Existing:**

370 int to = max_record_pick_up;

371 List rcInfoList = new ArrayList();

**After some settings change:**

370 int to = max_record_pick_up;

```
  Some warning message started showing here for the next line...
```

371 List rcInfoList = new ArrayList();

I am not sure how this warning message between two lines got enabled, may be some configurations enabled mistakenly.

Can anyone help me to stop showing this warning message between two lines?

Comment: Please don't post text output as images. It's difficult to see on a small screen, can't be interpreted by text-to-speech, can't be copy-pasted as search term...  please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1778238/edit) the question to put it in as text. As you say you're happy to check the warnings - what do you see if you do?

Comment: Edited. given some example. But the image also kept for reference.

Comment: Why are you still using raw types? Generics types were introduced in Java 5 - 19 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by myself.

Go to Window > Preferences

Then search for `Code Mining`

Then select Text Editors and select `None` for Show code minings for problem annotations.

[image]